# Average moving window in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

How can I calculate the average moving window in Google Earth Engine? I want to apply it over SWIR1 band to map water bodies. Specifically, I want to know which functions I should use. Based on search,

```
Reducer.mean()
kernel.square()
Focal_mean()
```

seem to be candidates.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options, one using `ee.Image.focal_mean()`, the other `ee.Image.reduceNeighborhood()`. I don't think it matters which of them you use (I'd be curios myself to hear if there is any difference).

```
var image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20190605T100039_20190605T100530_T32TQM')
var focalMean = image.focal_mean(30, 'square', 'meters')
var reduceNeighborhood = image.reduceNeighborhood(
  ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  ee.Kernel.square(30, 'meters')
).regexpRename('(.*)_mean', '$1') // Drop the _mean part of the band names

var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3' ,'B2'], min: 300, max: 3000, gamma: 1.5}
Map.addLayer(image, visParams, 'image')
Map.addLayer(focalMean, visParams, 'focalMean')
Map.addLayer(reduceNeighborhood, visParams, 'reduceNeighborhood')
Map.centerObject(ee.Geometry.Point([12.49247, 41.89021]), 14)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1ea633ac2d353b419a4b23b511513c3a